# Redis publish in rails 4 stops server thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, server-sent-events

Sorry for english, i'm newbie.

Trying to use redis.publish feature with rails 4 and redis gem to push messages with SSE.

I have this block in my controller

```
logger.info "test1"
$redis.publish "user", "test"
logger.info "test2"
```

where $redis -

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379, :db => 1,:timeout => 0)
```

in initializer.

Server console in production print

```
I, [2013-08-07T22:34:50.138232 #4679]  INFO -- : test1
```

And then nothing. Another request working, but this thread stops.

By the way, this `$redis.publish "user", "test"` at `RAILS_ENV=production rails console` run perfectly and message successfully appear at client.

Can you help me?

UPD: Ruby 2.0-p247, Rails 4, Redis 3.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use one connection in initializer to subscribe and publish both.

I created 2 connections, 1 for subscribe in sse writer, 1 in controllers to publish, and everything working normally.